# Graphing Summation in R

Tags: r

Went back and tried to make some corrections...hopefully this makes more sense now.

I'm trying to plot $sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( ( 2^{-k\gamma} +1 ) ^ \gamma \right)$ as a function of gamma in R, but I'm not sure how to write summations in R? Can I even do that?

This is what thought...

```
g = seq(2, 16, length.out = 10)

f = sum( ( 2^{-k * g} +1 ) ^ g )? (I know this is wrong/ I don't know what to do with k)

plot(g, f, type="l", col="blue")
```

Comment: You've got some major syntax errors. You haven't defined `x`, `k`, `gamma`. I'm not sure if you're trying to make `f` a function or a vector. All functions in R take their arguments in parentheses `()`, whereas square brackets `[]` are used for taking subsets, so when you have `sum[2...]` you are trying to subset the `sum` function. `infinity` isn't defined in R, instead `Inf` is used as a "value" for infinity, but `sum` is for summing values you pass in, not for analytically evaluating expressions...

Comment: Is this Mathematica syntax? Are you looking for an R solution, or is your question mis-tagged?

Comment: And as you don't refer to `g` or `x` in your `f`, I'm not even really sure what you're trying to plot. Are you wanting vary `k` or `gamma` on the x-axis? Or have the x-axis represent individual terms? Or something else? Overall, I'd recommend taking a step back and reading through some introductory R materials. There's quite a few resources in the R tag wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function `f` that accepts a scalar `g` and evaluate it at every element of the vector `g`.  Then plot it.

```
g <- seq(2, 16, length.out = 10)

f <- function(g, n = 20) {
  k <- 1:n
  sum( ( 2^{-k * g} + 1 ) ^ g )
}

y <- sapply(g, f)
plot(g, y, col = "blue", type = "l", ylab = "f")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]